# Is there a way to convert this delphi code to c++builder

Tags: delphi, c++builder-10.1-berlin

In most cases I am able to convert Delphi to C++, but this one gives me some headache. Maybe some of you could help.

As seen in this link [here](http://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/using-timagelist-with-tlistview), which references some new functions on TListView in Embarcadero (FMX). As I am much more comfortable with C++ than Delphi I use C++Builder. In most cases this is quite Ok to translate and understand, and find workarounds. But here I am stuck:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
I: Integer;
begin
// ListView1 uses a classic Appearance
for I in [0..63] do
with ListView1.Items.Add do
begin
  Text := Format('%d pages', [1000 + Random(1234567)]);
  Detail := Format('%d kg of paper', [1000 + Random(1234)]);
  ImageIndex := Random(ImageList1.Count);
end;

// ListView4 uses a dynamic appearance with items named
// Text1, Detail1, Portrait
for I in [0..63] do
with ListView4.Items.Add do
begin
  Data['Text1'] := Format('%d pages', [1000 + Random(1234567)]);
  Data['Detail1'] := Format('%d kg of paper', [1000 + Random(1234)]);
  Data['Portrait'] := Random(ImageList1.Count);
end;
end;

end.
```

The section I am struggling with is

```
with ListView4.Items.Add do
begin
  Data['Text1'] := Format('%d pages', [1000 + Random(1234567)]);
  Data['Detail1'] := Format('%d kg of paper', [1000 + Random(1234)]);
  Data['Portrait'] := Random(ImageList1.Count);
end;
```

How is this translated, or is this functionality which simply doesn't exists in c++ ?

Comment: What exactly are you stuck on

Comment: Answer: Yes, there is a way. <g>

Comment: Why would you ? C++B can compile Delphi code - so just let it be there until you would have to heavily remake that form

Comment: @Arioch'The Because you don't know Delphi, and you don't want to have a mixed language code base

Comment: @DavidHeffernan you already have it. Now you can go translating for mere translating or solve the problems when they are coming.

Comment: @Arioch'The Maybe if you don't care that your code is a giant ball of spaghetti

Comment: Guess "Spaghetti code" does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: @Arioch'The You are being naive here. You are really going to convert your entire form from C++ to Delphi just to call once function? Honestly, what you are thinking of is beyond me. Sure, if you have a large coherent library, then keep it in its original language. But if you have what appears to be an excerpt, then that would be silly.

Comment: 1) I already made an exemption "until you would have to heavily remake that form" and 2) "you have a large coherent library" is probably largely true. How could a person that hardly knows Delphi get into coding a Delphi up? Most natural way is by inheriting it from the previous Delphi-writing authors. So he really does have the "coherent Delphi legacy app" that he now gradually remaking into the language of his own liking. Should it be done in Waterfall style? There are some bonuses in it, but some drawbacks too.

Comment: I have no idea what any of that meant.

Comment: Actually three things: 1. The 'with' keyword in Delphi, how would you translate that. 2. My Basic knowledge of arrays (here Data []) is that you can't use text as an index. Clearly I have missed something, or is this proprietary for C++Builder/Delphi. 3. Is it possible to set Data['Portrait'] to an ImageIndex Bitmap ? Instead. Or are you bound to the fact it is just 'itemindex' from TListView you are referencing?

Comment: All that info should be in the question. And it'snreally three questions then.

Comment: You're right, but I see now that some of theese question are answered below.

Comment: Doesn't matter. Care about future readers. Improve the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you want to add an item to a ListView you need to first create an item object (TListViewItem*) using Add() function that is child of TListView's Items property.
Then, the Data property of item is expecting TValue, so you need to get TValue from a string or something else you want to put in the item. 
Remember to use BeginUpdate() before fragment where you are adding items to ListView and EndUpdate() after to improve the performance of this operation.

```
ListView4->BeginUpdate();

TListViewItem* item = ListView4->Items->Add();
UnicodeString string1 = "content of the String";

item->Data["Text1"] =  TValue::From<UnicodeString>(string1);
item->Data["Detail1"] = TValue::From<UnicodeString>(string1); 
item->Data["visitTime"] =TValue::From<int>(Random(ImageList1->Count)) 

ListView4->EndUpdate();
```

Answer (score 3):

`With` kind of introduces an unnamed variable and a scope for it. In C++ you have to be explicit. The Delphi fragment is equivalent to

```
var
  li: TListItem;
begin
  li := ListView4.Items.Add;
  li.Data['Text1'] := Format('%d pages', [1000 + Random(1234567)]);
  li.Data['Detail1'] := Format('%d kg of paper', [1000 + Random(1234)]);
  li.Data['Portrait'] := Random(ImageList1.Count);
end;
```

(if I didn't mess up :-)).

Comment: Note that many consider `with` as the spawn of the devil. In these days, with much more varied scopes, especially object scope, it can cause very hard to find bugs. In the olden days, when scopes were much easier to follow, when Wirth designed Pascal, it made sense, as a simplification and an optimization.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I still consider moderate WITH use a good optimization following DRY/Single Responsibility principles. In C++ I can declare new variables in every begin/end block. Pascal prohibits it. In many modern languages I also can have single-assignment var, something akin to `begin const F = Self.Canvas.Font; F.Style := ...; ...; end;` - and yet again Delphi lacks it. In a sense, `With` is a substitute to both this features lacking in Delphi. That said, because that "implicit variable" is unnamed overuse of With really easily turns into a nightmare

Comment: Strangely the OP mentioned he was stuck in `with ListView4.Items.Add` section. but did not mentioned the first section `with ListView1.Items.Add do` which has almost the same code... Although I gave +1 to this answer, this fact and @Davids comment made me think `with` is not the issue.

Comment: @kobik, it just seemed obvious to me that the OP struggles with the `with`. Especially with the "functionality which simply doesn't exists in c++". We'll have to wait for the OP. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```cpp
// Never use the OnCreate event in C++,
// use the class constructor instead...
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    // ListView1 uses a classic Appearance
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        TListViewItem *Item = ListView1->Items->Add();
        Item->Text = Format(L"%d pages", ARRAYOFCONST(( 1000 + Random(1234567) )) );
        Item->Detail = Format(L"%d kg of paper", ARRAYOFCONST(( 1000 + Random(1234) )) );
        Item->ImageIndex = Random(ImageList1->Count);
    }

    // ListView4 uses a dynamic appearance with items named
    // Text1, Detail1, Portrait
    for(int i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        TListViewItem *Item = ListView4->Items->Add();
        Item->Data[L"Text1"] = Format(L"%d pages", ARRAYOFCONST(( 1000 + Random(1234567) )) );
        Item->Data[L"Detail1"] = Format(L"%d kg of paper", ARRAYOFCONST(( 1000 + Random(1234) )) );
        Item->Data[L"Portrait"] = Random(ImageList1->Count);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Arioch'The `OnCreate` *can* be triggered in the base class constructor before the derived class is constructed, which is OK in Delphi but illegal in C++. `OnDestroy` has similar illegal behavior, as it *can* be triggered in the base class destructor after the derived class has been destructed, which is again OK in Delphi but illegal in C++. Now granted, the behavior is linked to the `OldCreateOrder` property, which is *usually* false (but not always!), but it is best to avoid the problem and NEVER use `OnCreate` and `OnDestroy` on C++, ALWAYS use the constructor and destructor instead.

Comment: Interesting.... Sounds like if in C++ it would have been always in `OldCreateOrder` fashion.... Once more I see how `AfterConstruction` and `BeforeDestruction` subroutines were a bright insight of AH. PS: there is yet another injection point here - `Loaded()` method. I'd prefer to override it than constructor, but it is matter of taste

Comment: AH was long gone when AC and BD were added. They arrived in D6 to deal with starting threads after derived constructors ran. I never use OnCreate or OnDestroy. Override constructor and destructor. Delphi programmers have learnt to be scared of that because they have been taught to let the IDE write their programs.

Comment: @Arioch'The: `OldCreateOrder` sets whether `OnCreate` is fired in the base class constructor or `AfterConstruction()`, and whether `OnDestroy` is fired in the base class destructor or `BeforeDestruction()`. The problem is, `OldCreateOrder` is *supposed* to always be false (it only exists for compatibility with very old legacy code), but *sometimes* older C++ IDEs would silently flip it to true and then people would wonder why their events were failing. Maybe that flip bug has been fixed over the years, but I don't trust those events. Rely on C++ semantics in C++ rather than Delphi semantics.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: `AfterConstruction()` and `BeforeDestruction()` existed long before D6.  `TThread` was simply *fixed* in D6 by finally using `AfterConstruction()`, which it was not previously using in earlier versions.

Comment: OK, you are right on that part of my comment, I was wrong, according to this post (http://www.drbob42.com/delphi4/d4constr.htm) they were added in D4. Anders left 2 years before then. Whether or not he had a part in AC and BD I don't know. I just somewhat rail against everyone assuming Delphi is a one dev show.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I just checked D5 RTL (1999) - there are both AC and BD. I do not have D2/D4 RTL now though and can not check there.

Comment: @Arioch D4, two years after AH left