# How to cast String to TValue?

Tags: c++builder, rtti

This code throws `Invalid typecast` at the last line `prop->SetValue(control, value)`.

I assume I am casting `"MyString"` incorrectly.  What's the right way to it?

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < MyForm->ControlCount; i++) {
    TControl *control = MyForm->Controls[i];
    if (control->Name == "MyTEdit") {
        TRttiContext ctx;
        TRttiType *type = ctx.GetType(control->ClassInfo());
        TRttiProperty *prop = type->GetProperty(L"Text");
        TValue value = TValue::From("MyString");
        prop->SetValue(control, value);
    }
}
```

It's supposed to loop through all the controls in `MyForm` until it finds the `TEdit` with the `Name` of `MyTEdit`, and change the text in the box to `MyString`.

My code is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53931205/c-builder-xe4-10-2-tokyo-tstreamwriter-clwhite-cannot-be-copied/53952403#53952403) answer.  Unfortunately it did not provide an example of casting a `String` literal so a `TValue` so I am at a loss.

## Update

After reading the answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39726386/is-there-a-way-to-convert-this-delphi-code-to-cbuilder) question, I changed `TValue value = TValue::From("MyString");` to this:

```cpp
String myString = "MyString";
TValue value = TValue::From<UnicodeString>(myString);
```

Now I get the following error:

```
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::Rtti::TValue __fastcall System::Rtti::TValue::From<System::UnicodeString>(System::UnicodeString)' referenced from UNIT1.OBJ
```

I have included this at the top of `Unit1.cpp`:

```cpp
#pragma explicit_rtti
#include <System.Rtti.hpp>
```

So I don't understand why it would say that.

## Update 2

The problem disappeared when I switched to 64 bit from 32 bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TValue::From<T>()` is a Delphi Generic method, and there are documented linker issues using Generics in C++:

[How to Handle Delphi Generics in C++](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Generics_in_C%2B%2B).

Try [using the assignment `operator=`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C%2B%2B_Assignment_Operator_as_the_Delphi_Implicit_Operator) instead, as `TValue` has an assignment operator for `UnicodeString`:

```cpp
String myString = "MyString";
TValue value;
value = myString;
```

```cpp
TValue value;
value = String("MyString");
```